# Можно ли Микеланджело приложить к папе Юлию II как "его Буонарроти"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, ономастика

> Но дни титанов, тех «которые приблизили Небо к Земле», как пишут о
>   деятелях эпохи Возрождения, их величественная задумка – **воина Юлия
>   Второго и его Буонарроти** – теперь живёт в одной только фигуре
>   <Моисея>, в паре скульптурных набросков да в нескольких рисунках.

Answer (score 1):

Более подходит «его гордый флорентиец». Конфликтов между Его святейшеством и Микеланджело было предостаточно, чтобы говорить только об уважительном сотрудничестве заказчика и исполнителя.